# Sorting months in a list

Tags: c#

I have a list of strings which contains months of the year.  I need to be able to sort this list so the months are in order by month, not alphabetically.  I have been searching for awhile but I can't see to wrap my head around any of the solutions I've found.

Here's an example of how the months might be added.  They are added dynamically based off of fields in a SharePoint list so they can be in any order and can have duplicates (I am removing these with Distinct()).

```
List<string> monthList = new List<string>();
monthList.Add("June");
monthList.Add("February");
monthList.Add("August");
```

Would like to reorder this to:

```
February
June
August
```

Comment: why don't you post back the month index or number?

Comment: What solutions have you found?  What part of those solutions were difficult to understand?

Comment: Although I need my months names to be in Romanian, this helps me a lot and I now know how to handle my problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could parse the string into a `DateTime` and then sort using the month integer property. See here for supported month names: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthnames.aspx

Something like this:

```
var sortedMonths = monthList
    .Select(x => new { Name = x, Sort = DateTime.ParseExact(x, "MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Sort.Month)
    .Select(x => x.Name)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: This actually worked like a champ for me.  Would you mind explaining how it works though?  This is one of the solutions I had hit before but I couldn't understand what each of those methods was doing.

Comment: The first `Select` will operate on each item in `monthList`, where it will create a new anonymous type with two properties: `Name` and `Sort`, where `Name` is the original string, e.g. "January", and `Sort` is the string parsed as a `DateTime`. The `OrderBy` can then order the sequence, and finally the sequence is projected back into its original form of just the month names. Hope that made any sense!

Answer (score 3):

You can parse month names into dates (it assumes the current year and day 1):

```
monthList = monthList.OrderBy(s=> DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MMMM", new CultureInfo("en-US"))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Dictionary<int,string>` instead, using the `int` as a month number for sorting, then sorting by key.

```
IDictionary<int,string> monthList = new Dictionary<int,string>();
monthList.Add(6, "June");
monthList.Add(2, "February");
monthList.Add(8, "August");

var sorted = monthList.OrderBy(item => item.Key);
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you would do it using a custom sort order over  the one provided by `DateTime` (after parsing)?

Comment: @seldon - Not really. Just extending what the OP was presenting. Depending on requirements, this may be all that he needs - if he needs a sorted list that is culture sensitive (and contains _all_ of the months), that's a different thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on having a list of only strings representing months, then you must use another data source to retrieve the index of that month by which you can sort the list.  For example, you could populate a dictionary with the month names as `string` keys and an `int` index as the value.  You can then use the overloaded method [`List<T>.Sort(Comparison<T>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) and pass in a comparison function that returns the index of the months by name (by passing them into the dictionary).

However, I would recommend not using a raw string in the first place, but rather a more structured data type representing a month.  You can then embed the index in the data structure itself and sort based on that value, thus giving you a more self-contained solution.

Comment: No, you don't need another data source for the index, at least not if you rely on parsing the month string into a `DateTime`, which provide all the rich data structure that you speak of.

Comment: @seldon: You need another sort key if you are dealing with raw strings as the code in the original question was.  It could be a `DateTime` as you mention or a separate `int` index or whatever is appropriate.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right. I was thinking of it more in terms of defining that key yourself or not.

Answer (score 1):

You need a SortedList<> .. such as

```
SortedList<int,string> monthList=new SortedList<int,string>();
monthList.Add(6,"June");
monthList.Add(2,"February");
monthList.Add(8,"August");   
IList<string> sortedMonthList=monthList.Values;
```

then use sortedMonthList for the rest.

This could be improved by using seldon's answer to create a function, just like

```
public static int MonthNumFromName(String monthname)
{ ... }
```

and then use

```
monthList.Add(MonthNumFromName("June"),"June");
```

above.

Comment: Seems like @Oded beat me to it with a slightly different approach

Answer (score 0):

Create an `enum` and assign `int` values for each month. Sort that thing with linq.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess there aren't any sorting techniques for this with just pure month as string.

You can just use a `Dictionary<int, string>` and use the int to sort your months.

If I haven't mistaken, you are actually having a List of months as string, then why don't you do this?

```
List<string> months = new List<string> { "January", "February", ..., "December" };

var yourSortedMonthsInYourOriginalList = months.Where(m => 
                                              originalList.Any(o => o == m)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own sort class:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> monthList = new List<string>();
        monthList.Add("June");
        monthList.Add("February");
        monthList.Add("August");

        monthList.Sort(new _mysort());

    }

    private class _mysort : IComparer<string>
    {

        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            if (x=="February" && y=="June")
            {
                return -1;
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }
```

But i think you should use an Enum, and convert it to string, then you can use the numeric to sort it.

```
 enum months
    {
        Jan =0,
        Feb =1
    }
```

like:

```
       List<months> mlist = new List<months>() { months.Feb, months.Jan };
        //sort
        mlist = mlist.OrderBy(e => (int)e).ToList();
       //print
        mlist.ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()));
```