# DateTimeFormatInfo.AbbreviatedMonthNames order

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a list of string that represents the Abbreviated months: `Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec`

If I get these values in random order, how can I order them as above: `Jan, Feb, Mar ...` ?

```
List<string> months = new List<string>();
```

Comment: why don't you manually `order` them once?

Comment: Why do you need to re-order this at all? Does it contain duplicates, is it actually a `List<CustomType>` with a string-property for month-name? Otherwise your requirement makes no sense. You could hold an ordered `List<string>` which contains all month-names and return/use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use this ordered list:

```
List<string> months = Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
    .Select(m => DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(m))
    .ToList();
```

list contains:

```
        [0] "Jan"   
        [1] "Feb"   
        [2] "Mar"   
        [3] "Apr"   
        [4] "May"   
        [5] "Jun"   
        [6] "Jul"   
        [7] "Aug"   
        [8] "Sep"   
        [9] "Oct"   
        [11] "Dec"
```

If you want the month names in your current language use:

```
DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(m)
```

If you now have another list that contains month-names and this list contains duplicates or is not complete but you want to order this list naturally, then you can use `IndexOf`:

```
monthList = monthList.OrderBy(s => months.IndexOf(s)).ToList();
```

Here's another approach that doesn't need another list to compare but that uses `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
monthList = monthList
    .OrderBy(s => DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MMM", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: And then you can say for example: `var sorted = new[] { "Feb", "Apr", "Jan" }.OrderBy(months.IndexOf);`

Comment: @Corak: to be honest, it doesn't make sense to order this array/list when you already have it. So i don't really underatand the requirement.

Comment: As I understood it, OP has a list of some but not all abbreviated month names and wants to sort them. If OP just needs a sorted list of abbreviated month names, then yes, `months` is sufficient.

Comment: @Corak: incomplete list makes sense, thanks. I've edited my answer. Added also an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

There is one already made for you :)

check it out from
[DateTimeFormatInfo.MonthNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthnames.aspx)

> public string[] MonthNames { get; set; }
>
> A one-dimensional array of type String containing the culture-specific full names of the months. In a 12-month calendar, the 13th element of the array is an empty string. The array for InvariantInfo contains "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", and "".

EDIT: I found [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539088/sorting-months-in-a-list)  it may be useful

Answer (score 0):

you could use `DateTime.ParseExact` method to achieve this

```
            var months = new[] { "Jan", "Apr", "Sep", "Oct", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Feb", "Mar", "Aug",  "Nov", "Dec" };
            var sortedMonthNames = months
            .Select(m => new {Name = m, Date = DateTime.ParseExact(m, "MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)})
            .OrderBy(m => m.Date.Month)
            .Select(m => m.Name)
            .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order and recreate the list ordered by month number:

```
string[] months = {"feb", "oct", "apr", "jan"};

List<string> orderedMonths = months.OrderBy(m => DateTime.Parse("2000" + m + "1")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ.OrderBy() method with help of string array with correct format and Array.IndexOf() method to compare values:

```
class Program
{
    static readonly string[] format = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };

    static void Main()
    {            
        string[] sorted = (new[] { "Jul", "Jan", "May" }).OrderBy(v => Array.IndexOf(format, v)).ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < sorted.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sorted[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output : Jan, May, Jul