# Sorting months according to calendar year

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

I currently have some code that can sort strings in alphabetic order. I would like for it to sort the months according to the calendar year. I have seen ways to do it on this website but cant apply them to my code specifically. What would I need to add to make it sort in order (January, February etc etc).

Code to read months to array:

```
var month1Values = File
    .ReadAllLines(monthFilePath)
    .Select(x => new { Name = monthFilePath, Sort = DateTime.ParseExact(x, "MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) })
    .ToArray();
```

Code to sort:

```
if (SortFile == 3)
{                 
    comparison1 = string.Compare(fileData[index].MonthValues, 
        fileData[index + 1].MonthValues) > 0;

    if (comparison1)
    {
        temp = fileData[index].MonthValues;
        fileData[index].MonthValues = fileData[index + 1].MonthValues;
        fileData[index + 1].MonthValues = temp;
        swap = true;
     }
 }
```

Error appears where asterix is:

```
for (var index = 0; index < datasize; index++)
            {
                fileData[index] = new FileData
                {
            DayValues = day1Values[index],
            MonthValues = *month1Values[index]*,

                 };
            }
```

Error reads cannot convert type '< annonymous type: string Name, System.DateTime Sort >' to 'string'. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: `I have seen ways to do it on this website` - Can you show us a [mcve] that uses one of these methods but does not work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539088/sorting-months-in-a-list but thats in a list

Comment: Why do you think it would work any differently with an array?  If you must, try calling `.ToList()` on the result of `ReadAllLines` and you'll have yourself a list to work with.

Comment: but I am still not understanding what to actually do?? I'm still relatively new to c#. Could you explain more extensively please?

Comment: The answers given in the linked question are quite clear.  If you are having trouble understanding them you either need a tutorial (off-topic for this site) or you need to be more specific about what is confusing you.

Comment: The problem is in applying it. When I implement it I get an error elsewhere in my code that says cannot complicity convert type anonymous string name etc etc etc to string

Comment: Then *post* that code as a [mcve] with the specific error message you are getting.

Comment: "When I implement it I get an error elsewhere in my code" Then that is what you should be posting!!!

Comment: I suspect that the line you want is `MonthValues = month1Values[index].Name;`. Hard to tell for sure, though.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating anonymous data types in your `Select` instruction (first code box, line 3) instead of relying on `DateTime` type. The runtime don't know how to cast your anonymous type to `String`.

This should work as expected:

```
.Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x, "MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

Be aware that normal `DateTime`->`String` cast involves creating a full date from only month given; this involves assuming that day and year is current with hour, minute and second zeroed out.